# One mysql table with many fields or many (hundreds of) tables with fewer fields?

Tags: sql, mysql

I am designing a system for a client, where he is able to create data forms for various products he sales him self. 
The number of fields he will be using will not be more than 600-700 (worst case scenario). As it looks like he will probably be in the range of 400 - 500 (max).

I had 2 methods in mind for creating the database (using meta data):

a) Create a table for each product, which will hold only fields necessary for this product, which will result to hundreds of tables but with only the neccessary fields for each product

or

b) use one single table with all availabe form fields (any range from current 300 to max 700), resulting in one table that will have MANY fields, of which only about 10% will be used for each product entry (a product should usualy not use more than 50-80 fields)

Which solution is best? keeping in mind that table maintenance (creation, updates and changes) to the table(s) will be done using meta data, so I will not need to do changes to the table(s) manually.

Thank you!

/**** UPDATE *****/

Just an update, even after this long time (and allot of additional experience gathered) I needed to mention that **not [normalizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your database is a terrible idea**. What is more, a not normalized database almost always (just always from my experience) indicates a flawed application design as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your key deciding factor is whether [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) is required. Even though you are only adding data using an application, you'll still  need to cater for anomalies, e.g. what happens if someone's phone number changes, and they insert multiple rows over the lifetime of the application? Which row contains the correct phone number?

As an example, you may find that you'll have [*repeating groups*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Repeating_groups) in your data, like one person with several phone numbers; rather than have three columns called "Phone1", "Phone2", "Phone3", you'd break that data into its own table.

There are other issues in normalisation, such as transitive or non-key dependencies. These concepts will hopefully lead you to a database table design without [modification anomalies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Free_the_database_of_modification_anomalies), as you should hope for!

Answer (score 4):

i would have 3 tables:

- product

  - id
  - name
  - whatever else you need
- field

  - id
  - field name
  - anything else you might need
- product_field

  - id
  - product_id
  - field_id
  - field value

Comment: Hello pulegium, 

I also thought of something similar, but there is one problem: the type of the field can be anything from bool to text. In this design there is no way to have the right field type for ecah field... (theoretically I could use TEXT as it can hold any of the values I need, but I would like to have the right type of field assigned to each of then)

Comment: unless I have more field_value fields with different field types... (field_value_int, field_value_text, field_value_decimal etc)... but that doesent feel very right ...? :)

Comment: Add a `field_type` column to the `field` table.  This would still leave you having to store everything as text in the database, but allows you to define your own validation rules for the field as needed.  This would give you all the flexibility of pulegium's design, plus you wouldn't be limited to just the types supported by your database engine, but would also be able to have, e.g., a `must_be_multiple_of_five_percent` validation (for discounts), `week_day_name` validation, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Pulegiums solution is a good way to go.

You do not want to go with the one-table-for-each-product solution, because the structure of your database should not have to change when you insert or delete a product. Only the rows of one or many tables should be inserted or deleted, not the tables themselves.

Answer (score 1):

While it's possible that it may be necessary, having that many fields for something as simple as a product list sounds to me like you probably have a flawed design.

You need to analyze your potential table structures to ensure that each field contains no more than one piece of information (e.g., "2 hammers, 500 nails" in a single field is bad) and that each piece of information has no more than one field where it belongs (e.g., having `phone1`, `phone2`, `phone3` fields is bad).  Either of these situations indicates that you should move that information out into a separate, related table with a foreign key connecting it back to the original table.  As pulegium has demonstrated, this technique can quickly break things down to three tables with only about a dozen fields total.